# Multiple-GPU training not available in caffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I run into problems when trying to use caffe with multiple gpus. When executing following command, I get the error log show below:

```
caffe train -solver $SOLVER -gpu 0,1 2>&1 | tee $LOGGING

F0409 14:17:22.355074 12079 caffe.cpp:254] Multi-GPU execution not available - rebuild with USE_NCCL
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x2aee66002b2d  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x2aee66004995  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x2aee660026a9  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x2aee6600542e  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @           0x40c172  train()
    @           0x4084f3  main
    @     0x2aee78f67b35  __libc_start_main
    @           0x408f0b  (unknown)
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong here? Is there some caffe bug which I am not aware of?

Comment: NCCL is used for multi gpu communication. You have to enable `USE_NCCL := 1` in makefile.config. Then rebuild.

Comment: Why did you leave a comment rather than answering the question? So I can't give you any credit. Yeah, I will try to do that! @Inman

Comment: Some solutions are too short to qualify as an answer.  @Inman did well to leave that as a comment.  :-)

Comment: I do not agree with you @Prune. I think it is more obvious when he just answers the question so that everyone can see it quickly without reading the comments.

Comment: So *you* write it as an answer and accept it.  It's not my place to do so.

Comment: I just wanted to give him the opportunity to give him the credit. I did not say so either. I was just kindly offering him or you the credit. @Prune

Answer (score 0):

1. Install CUDA
2. Install cuDNN
3. Install Dependencies

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libopencv-dev libhdf5-serial-dev protobuf-compiler libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev liblmdb-dev libatlas-base-dev git  
   $ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends libboost-all-dev
   ```
4. Install NCCL

   NVIDIA NCCL is required to run Caffe on more than one GPU. NCCL can be installed with the following commands:

   ```
   $ git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/nccl.git
   $ cd nccl
   $ sudo make install -j
   ```

   NCCL libraries and headers will be installed in `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`.
5. Install Caffe

   Uncomment the line `USE_CUDNN := 1`. This enables cuDNN acceleration.
   Uncomment the line `USE_NCCL := 1`. This enables NCCL which is required to run Caffe on multiple GPUs.

   Save and close the file. You're now ready to compile Caffe.

   ```
   $ make all -j
   ```

   When this command completes, the Caffe binary will be available at build/tools/caffe.